# How to apply the apply the RenderTransform in code behind in c#?

Tags: c#

I am new for RenderTransform, I need to apply the below RenderTransform in code behind(C#)

```
  <local:Container.RenderTransform>
         <CompositeTransform x:Name="visualCoinatiner_transform" />
  </local:Container.RenderTransform>
```

Any suggestion on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can apply the RenderTransform in code behind like below code,

```
private CompositeTransform _compositeTransform;
_compositeTransform = new CompositeTransform();
this.RenderTransform = _compositeTransform;
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, thank you for this answer. Just to build on it a little, flip a MediaPlayerElement both horizontally and vertically:

```
thisMPElement = Canvas.FindName("NameOfXAMLElement") as MediaPlayerElement;
var cp = new CompositeTransform()
{
    ScaleX = -1,
    ScaleY = -1
};
thisMPElement.RenderTransform = cp;
```